# Math through multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, html

getting no errors but trying to loop through all the inputs and add them all to the total (var = paidTotal). The first input works but the rest don't when others are added with an add button. Something wrong with the loop?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxFields = 20;
    var addButton = $('#plusOne');
    var deleteButton = $('#minusOne');
    var wrapper = $('#userNumbers');
    var fieldInput = '<div><input type="text" name="persons" id="persons"/></div>';
    var x = 1;

    $(addButton).click(function () {
        if (x < maxFields) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append(fieldInput);
        }
    });

    $(deleteButton).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var myNode = document.getElementById("userNumbers");
        i=myNode.childNodes.length - 1;
        if(i>=0){
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.childNodes[i]);
        x--;
        }

    });

});

function peoplePaid() {
    var checkTotal = document.getElementById('check').value;
    var personsCheck = document.getElementById('personsCheck').value;
    var paidTotal = document.getElementById('paidTotal');

    for(var i = 1; i < personsCheck.length; i+=1){
        personsCheck[i] += paidTotal;
    }
    paidTotal.innerHTML = checkTotal - personsCheck;
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$ <input type="text" id="check" value="" />

<button type="button" id="plusOne">+</button>
<button type="button" id="minusOne">-</button>

<div id="userNumbers">
<div class="">
<input type="text" id="personsCheck" name="person">
</div>

<button onclick="peoplePaid()">Calculate</button>
<!--Paid Amount-->
<div>
<h3>Paid Amount: <span id="paidTotal"></span></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: var personsCheck = document.getElementById('personsCheck').value; give you teh value of text input not the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it as class

```
<input type="text" class="personsCheck" name="person">
```

and access it by

```
    var personsCheck = document.getElementsByClassName('personsCheck');
```

Answer (score 1):

ids have to be unique.  You'll only get one element from document.getElementById().

Try using a class instead, something like

```
    var fieldInput = '<div><input type="text" name="persons" class="persons"/></div>';
```

and use document.getElementsByClassName('persons') to get an array of all of the input fields that have that class.

Answer (score 1):

Your code logic is not something what you want to achieve.

I can not find any logic to use the input element with `id=personsCheck`.

First of all, you are appending input element with same `id` again and again which is invalid, because in a document `id` attribute must be unique. Use class attribute instead.

To get the total you can first get the elements with `querySelectorAll()`, theb use `forEach()` to loop through all of them to add one by one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxFields = 20;
    var addButton = $('#plusOne');
    var deleteButton = $('#minusOne');
    var wrapper = $('#userNumbers');
    var fieldInput = '<div><input type="text" name="persons" class="persons"/></div>';
    var x = 1;

    $(addButton).click(function () {
        if (x < maxFields) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append(fieldInput);
        }
    });

    $(deleteButton).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var myNode = document.getElementById("userNumbers");
        i=myNode.childNodes.length - 1;
        if(i>=0){
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.childNodes[i]);
        x--;
        }

    });

});

function peoplePaid() {
    var checkTotal = Number(document.getElementById('check').value);
    var persons = document.querySelectorAll('.persons');
    var personsCheck = Number(document.getElementById('personsCheck').value)
    var paidTotal = document.getElementById('paidTotal');
    var total = 0;
    persons.forEach(function(p){
      total += Number(p.value);
    });
    
    paidTotal.textContent = checkTotal - total;
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$ <input type="text" id="check" value="" />

<button type="button" id="plusOne">+</button>
<button type="button" id="minusOne">-</button>

<div id="userNumbers">
<div class="">
<input type="text" id="personsCheck" name="person">
</div>

<button onclick="peoplePaid()">Calculate</button>
<!--Paid Amount-->
<div>
<h3>Paid Amount: <span id="paidTotal"></span></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I ran your code snippet and it always subtracts, or does something that is unexpected? I'm not going to minus 1 because I don't have 125 reputation, but also because your explanation is good enough to get him on the right track. Just suggest that you might want to look into the snippet.

Comment: @SharpIncTechAndProgramming,----- `getting no errors but trying to loop through all the inputs and add them all to the total (var = paidTotal).` .......indicates question being asked to add not delete.........thanks.